# Change language and layout direction in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I'm using SwiftUI, and I know that the easiest way of localization is to add languages, and leave it to the OS to determine which language to use. But in my case, I need to determine a specific default language for the app, because:

1. The app MUST be in Arabic (RTL), and the other choice could be English (LTR).
2. In my country, many mobile (and mac) users tend to use English as the language of their devices interface.

The perfect solution is to make user able to switch between Arabic and English after installing the app (on first use), or in Settings, like the following example:

[image]

I tried to change `locale` and `layoutDirection` of the Content View, but it doesn't change the app layout to RTL:

```
import SwiftUI
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: MyDocument()) { file in
            ContentView(document: file.$document)
                .environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "ar"))
                .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative solution that would also work for me (if there is no perfect way to answer the above problem) is to totally remove the English (and Base) localization, and stick to only Arabic (RTL) by default, how?

Comment: Setting custom environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft) modifier on ContentView makes almost everything right-to-left in the app I work on (tested on simulator). The app is built using most of the standard components from the SwiftUI. Maybe the case is your app uses some hardcoded layout in custom components?

Comment: also, make sure you have added the Arabic localization in Xcode project "Localizations"

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for forcing RTL when the device's language is set to English.

```
List(items, id: \.id) { item in
    Cell(item: item)
        .environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "ar"))
}
.environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think change app language from product / scheme / edit / then set the app language to arabic may help but this may lead you to another error when you tries to change the language to English